# Zoom the picture within the picturebox of Visual Studio C++

Tags: c++, image, visual-studio, visual-c++

I have a problem about zooming into the picture displayed in a picturebox `Picture Control`. The expected result is similar to the following link: [A scrollable, zoomable, and scalable picture box](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15373/A-scrollable-zoomable-and-scalable-picture-box). The picture is zoomed in within the picturebox. Note the picturebox is zoomed in.

However, this can be implemented in .NET Framework 2.0. I have searched some information on the Internet, but none used C/C++ Windows API of Visual Studio. How can I zoom a picture within a the picturebox `Picture Control` when I work on Windows Forms of Visual Studio C++ 2010. Thank you for anyone's reply.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you mean by "zoom a picture within picture box"? Do you mean drawing a portion of image fit within a static control? And by saying "work on Windows Forms of VS C++ 2010 ", you mean using managed C# code in C++?

Comment: I want to zoom out local part of picture and show in the picturebox. Besides, I can use mouse to move scope showed in the picturebox. This effect is similar to the microscope. And I don't use managed C#.Thank you.

Comment: Ok, that is clear, atleast we are fully in winapi world. And probably, by picture box, you mean a static control in a dialog box. Don't you? It would be easy if you can share some code, not necessarily the entire source.

Comment: I don't have any idea. the code I have now is just input image into the picturebox.

Comment: I have thought out an idea. I use a picturebox(A) and I load my picture into it. Then, could I use another picturebox to show the local part of picturebox(A)? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any source code, it is difficult to comment.
StackOverflow is for problem solving; we can troubleshoot your starting code and get it working and during the course of which we can also fine tune design.

Anyway, I would like to give some pointers:

1. One or two picture boxes: entirely depends on your UI requirement.
2. Showing full or partial region of an image: `StretchBlt` is a powerful
   API that can be used to achieve. See [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145120(v=vs.85).aspx) for details.
3. Which class to use for picture box: if MFC is being used, then
   derive a class from CStatic, overload the OnPaint() and use
   StretchBlt to paint the image.
4. Classes to use for image: `CBitmap`, `CImage`, `Gdiplus::Image`. 
   Each have their own pros and cons.
   If transparent images/PNGs are to be suported, better go for `CImage` or  `Gdiplus::Image`.
   You can get enough info here: 
    [CBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t1yfd35.aspx) 
    [CImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwea7by5.aspx) 
    [Gdiplus::Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534462(v=vs.85).aspx)

Hope this would give you some starter.

Comment: Thank you very much for your common. I have found a method. I put the PictureBox in the Panel which is similar to the container. I am able to zoom in the PictureBox within that Panel and without going beyond the scope of the window.

Comment: glad to be of help. Close the question if the problem is solved by marking as answer. otherwise, please let me know so that i can improve the answer.

Answer (score 3):

I have faced the same issue and I searched a lot but didn't get the solution in cpp(freely available in c# and VB).
     So finally i decided to implement it by my own. If your Image size is bigger than the picture box then only 1 level of zoom(original size of image) you can do with my implementation.
     I will help you with the implementation. In current implementation
 if you do left click of mouse it will ZoomIn and
 if you do right click of mouse it will ZoomOut.

Assuming you have read the image file(.png, .jpg, .bmp, ...) in bmpPicture.

Bitmap ^bmpPicture = gcnew Bitmap(strFilename);// if not it can help

```
      private: System::Void pictureBox1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

     MouseEventArgs ^ms = (MouseEventArgs^)e;

                             if (ms->Button == System::Windows::Forms::MouseButtons::Left)
                             {
                                int pbx = ms->X;
                                int pby = ms->Y;

                                int  img_x = (pbx * mwidth / pbwidth * 1.0f);
                                int img_y = (pby * mheight / pbheight * 1.0f);

                                 pictureBox1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(pbx - img_x, pby - img_y);
                                 pictureBox1->SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode::AutoSize;
                                 pictureBox1->Image = bmpPicture;
    }
    else if(ms->Button == System::Windows::Forms::MouseButtons::Right)
    {

                                 int pbx = ms->X;
                                 int pby = ms->Y;

                                 pictureBox1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(0, 0);
                                 pictureBox1->SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode::StretchImage;
                                 pictureBox1->Image = bmpPicture;

    }
    }

    Hope this will help you...
```